# Static Object in Jboss using EJB3

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb-3.0

is it possible to create something like static object using EJB3 in Jboss. in other words i need to create something like a static object using singleton pattern or something like that, that is because i need to preload a configuration from database and i want that every bean that jboss creates uses this class to read this configuration instead of that every bean load it from the database.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB 3.1 does have a standard `@Singleton` annotation but EJB 3.0 doesn't. However, JBoss offers a JBoss extension to the EJB 3.0 spec to create a singleton with the `@Service` annotation.

From the JBoss EJB 3.0 Reference Documentation:

> ### [Chapter 6. JBoss EJB 3.0 extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html)
>
> JBoss provides a few extensions to the
>   EJB 3.0 spec. This chapter describes
>   those features here.
>
> #### 6.1. @Service EJBs
>
> An extension offered by JBoss EJB 3.0
>   is the notion of a
>   `@org.jboss.annotation.ejb.Service`
>   annotated bean. They are singleton
>   beans and are not pooled, so only one
>   instance of the bean exists in the
>   server. They can have both `@Remote` and
>   `@Local` interfaces so they can be
>   accessed by java clients. When
>   different clients look up the
>   interfaces for `@Service` beans, all
>   clients will work on the same instance
>   of the bean on the server. When
>   installing the bean it gets given a
>   JMX ObjectName in the MBean server it
>   runs on. The default is
>
> ```
> jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,name=<Fully qualified name of @Service bean>,type=service
> ```
>
> You can override this default
>   ObjectName by specifying the
>   `objectName` attribute of the
>   `@Service` annotation.

#### References

- JBoss EJB 3.0 Reference Documentation

  - [6.1. @Service EJBs](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html)
- JBoss EJB3 Tutorials

  - [Chapter 28. Service POJOs (JBoss extension of EJB3)](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Service_POJOs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bean with @Singleton annotation should work. Place your database initialize code in @PostConstruct & can release/cleanup in @PreDestroy.